# Apache Flink sink doesn't get invoked when using ProcessFunction or RichFlatMapFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

My Flink application reads data from one kafka source, maps it into an object and writes to another kafka topic. All works fine if I use `MapFunction` to transform but as soon as I use an implementation that `extends ProcessFunction or RichFlatMapFunction` classes, sink doesn't get called (write to kafka topic code doesn't get executed) at all. The reason I'm using `ProcessFunction` or `RichFlatMapFunction` is because I need RuntimeConext() to read and write ValueState. How should I achieve calling of sink in this case?

> env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("READ_FROM_TOPIC", new
> Deserializer(), pros)).keyBy(Order::getId)
> .process(new StatefulOrderMapper()).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>("WRITE_TO_TOPIC", new Serializer(), props)); // StatefulOrderMapper extends ProcessFunction
>
> env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("READ_FROM_TOPIC", new
> Deserializer(), pros)).keyBy(Order::getId)
> .map(new DoSomeMapping()).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>("WRITE_TO_TOPIC", new OrderSerializer(), props)); //DoSomeMapping extends MapFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference between map and flatmap or process is that a map emits the return value of the MapFunction, whereas a FlatMap or a ProcessFunction uses a Collector to emit events.

For a working example you can use as a starting point, I suggest taking a look at https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/batch-and-streaming-with-the-apache-flink-table-and-datastream-apis/#the-datastream-workflow. You'll find the code in https://github.com/immerok/recipes/tree/main/latest-transaction.

Note: I work for Immerok.

Comment: Andeson, thank you, it worked! can I ask another question: when I map source msg into an Order object, I would like to pass it to other mapper functions depending on the status of it, so all seven mappers act like a state machine (FSM). For example, I've 6 more functions like StatefulOrderMapper class and I would Flink to treat them as 7 states/nodes of FSM. The only way I could think of was, put all 7 in a consecutive chain and have logic inside each node to decide if it should process it or not. Doesn't look elegant though.

Comment: Flink has a CEP library for pattern matching with FSMs. See https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/pattern-matching-with-cep/ for an introduction. It can also be used from Flink SQL: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/match_recognize/